# I'm feeling better "after"/"by"/"from" drinking water

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the difference between the following sentences?

1. I'm feeling better ***after*** drinking water.
2. I'm feeling better ***by*** drinking water.
3. I'm feeling better ***from*** drinking water.

Answer (score 0):

While there are no inherent differences in the overall meaning of the above sentences(if you look at the bigger picture), the sentences are different if you dig deeper.

1) I'm feeling better after drinking water  : The emphasis is on time in this sentence. The fact that some time has passed after drinking water is what is making him feel better.

2)I'm feeling better by drinking water : The emphasis is on the action of drinking water.

3)I'm feeling better from drinking water : The emphasis is on the object. Water is making him feel better.